# Token amount calculation to set slippage for Pancakeswap tx

Tags: web3.py, python, pancakeswap

I have a simple code to calculates the needed token amount for the cases when I buy a token with 5% slippage. I just simply check how many tokens could I receive for the current price, get its 95% and use the amount for the `swapExactETHForTokens` function's `amountOutMin`. My question is that should I pay attention for the decimal of the token? Is there any scenario when I have to use it to calculate the correct token number which fits to the slippage?

This is how I do it now. I don't use the decimal at all.

```
def get_slippage(token_price, budget, slippage_percentage):
    original_amount = round(budget / token_price)
    one_percent = original_amount / 100
    token_amount_slippage_5p = round(one_percent * slippage_percentage)
    return token_amount_slippage_5p
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need to worry about the decimals. You cannot use absolute values because it will mean a completely different number, `100` for a token with 18 decimals would mean `10 ** 16`, if there are sandwiches out there, they will sandwich all of it and you will get exactly that, `minOut` is an important parameter to protect yourself against big slippage and sandwiches.

Comment: 18 decimals wouldn't be 10 ** 18 instead of 10 ** 16?